# How to simulate or trigger a Machine Check Exception?

Tags: linux, hardware, simulation

I've setup the `mcelog` tool on my Linux server, and I'd like to verify that it's working properly but I'm not sure how to test it.

Does anyone know of any ways to generate or trigger an exception event so I confirm that the hardware errors are logged correctly.

Answer (score 3):

mcelog [includes a test suite](http://mcelog.org/README.html) with a tool called `mce-inject`, designed to do exactly this.  The developer has [a copy of the source on github](https://github.com/andikleen/mce-inject).  It seems to require Linux 2.6.31 or better.

Comment: Can you explain more?? How to execute and how properly user this!! This may help new comers!